# How to read from a cluster using Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive

Consider I have a certain data distributed on many computers in my cluster.

How Can I load my data using Hive without worrying about it location?

Thanks

Comment: If you mean how to load data from your local machine into a table run the following from the hive shell. "load data local inpath '/path/on/local/filesystem/file.txt' into table table_name;"

Comment: No I don't mean load data from my local machine. @SailorLeroy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See detail below how to load data into Hive from HDFS.

**Loading files into tables**

Hive does not do any transformation while loading data into tables. Load operations are currently pure copy/move operations that move datafiles into locations corresponding to Hive tables.

**Syntax**

```
LOAD DATA INPATH 'filepath' [OVERWRITE] INTO TABLE tablename [PARTITION (partcol1=val1, partcol2=val2 ...)]
```

**Synopsis**

Load operations are currently pure copy/move operations that move datafiles into locations corresponding to Hive tables.

**i)-**
**filepath can be:**

- a relative path, such as project/data1
- an absolute path, such as /user/hive/project/data1
- a full URI with scheme and (optionally) an authority, such as
  hdfs://namenode:9000/user/hive/project/data1

**ii)-**
The target being loaded to can be a table or a partition. If the table is partitioned, then one must specify a specific partition of the table by specifying values for all of the partitioning columns.

**iii)-**
filepath can refer to a file (in which case Hive will move the file into the table) or it can be a directory (in which case Hive will move all the files within that directory into the table). In either case, filepath addresses a set of files.

**iv)-**
If the keyword LOCAL is not specified, then Hive will either use the full URI of filepath, if one is specified, or will apply the following rules:

- If scheme or authority are not specified, Hive will use the scheme
  and authority from the hadoop configuration variable fs.default.name
  that specifies the Namenode URI.
- If the path is not absolute, then Hive will interpret it relative to
  /user/
- Hive will move the files addressed by filepath into the table (or
  partition)

**v)-**
If the OVERWRITE keyword is used then the contents of the target table (or partition) will be deleted and replaced by the files referred to by filepath; otherwise the files referred by filepath will be added to the table.

- Note that if the target table (or partition) already has a file whose
  name collides with any of the filenames contained in filepath, then
  the existing file will be replaced with the new file.

See full detail from following link.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML

Comment: I read it on the apache link a couple of days ago, but this is not the answer to my question

Comment: can you put more detail about your requirement?